# How to override terminal font-family for specific glyph?

Tags: fonts, fontconfig, emoji, alacritty

I have set `Source Code Pro` as my default monospace font and `Noto Color Emoji` for emojis, set in fontconfig as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <alias>
    <family>serif</family>
    <prefer>
      <family>Noto Color Emoji</family>
      <family>DejaVu Sans</family>
    </prefer>
  </alias>
  <alias>
    <family>sans-serif</family>
    <prefer>
      <family>Noto Color Emoji</family>
      <family>DejaVu Serif</family>
    </prefer>
  </alias>
  <alias>
    <family>monospace</family>
    <prefer>
      <family>Noto Color Emoji</family>
      <family>Source Code Pro</family>
    </prefer>
  </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

This works fine for Gnome apps, but my terminal [Allacritty] still shows some emojis without using the emoji font. I suspect that is due to `Source Code Pro` having those glyphs because they work as expected with other fonts (e.g. Inconsolata).

For example ☕ and  emojis:

[image]

Is there how to force the emoji font to be used for those glyphs also in terminal?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a very similar fontconfig-config. Adding this helped:

```xml
  <match target="scan">
    <test name="family" compare="contains">
      <string>Source</string>
    </test>
    <edit name="charset" mode="assign" binding="same">
      <minus>
        <name>charset</name>
        <charset>
          <int>0x2611</int> <!-- ☑ -->
          <int>0x2615</int> <!-- ☕ -->
          <int>0x263a</int> <!-- ☺ -->
          <int>0x2665</int> <!-- ♥ -->
          <int>0x2713</int> <!-- ✓ -->
          <int>0x2714</int> <!-- ✔ -->
          <int>0x2764</int> <!-- ❤ -->
          <int>0x1f4a9</int> <!--  -->
          <int>0x1f916</int> <!--  -->
        </charset>
      </minus>
    </edit>
  </match>
```

It hides the specified codepoints from fonts matching `Source`. Ranges are also possible:

```xml
      <minus>
        <name>charset</name>
        <charset>
          <range>
            <int>0x1f600</int>
            <int>0x1f640</int>
          </range>
        </charset>
      </minus>
```

Make sure to run `fc-cache -f` afterwards. This did not work in every program, for example it worked for `xfce4-terminal` but not `alacritty` (even after a reboot).

I could not find much documentation for it, apart from [this bug report](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/fontconfig/fontconfig/-/issues/135) and the bug report linked within. [The manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/5/fonts-conf) is rather terse but might be helpful to understand the snippet better.

Comment: Interesting. But Alacritty is the first place I would need that. :( I'll try to teak this a bit and understand the config better to see if I can come up with a solution. Thanks.